# Why am I getting segmentation fault on my code?

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to add  an item to the linked list by traversing the list to create the next node. and the last node in the list to point to the newly created node. But I am getting a core dump segmentation fault on it.

```
void linked_list_add(list_node_t *head, void *item)
{
    list_node_t *temp = head;

    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    list_node_t *new_node = (list_node_t *)malloc(sizeof(list_node_t));

    new_node->data = item;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    new_node->prev = temp;

    //if(temp != NULL)
       // temp->next = new_node;
       // new_node->prev = temp;

}

TEST_F(LinkedList, Add)
{
    int i = 3;
    linked_list_add(list, &i);

    ASSERT_EQ(list->next->data, &i);

    i = 4;
    linked_list_add(list, &i);

    ASSERT_EQ(list->prev->data, &i);

    i = 5;
    linked_list_add(list, &i);

    ASSERT_EQ(list->next->data, &i);
}
```

Comment: could `temp` ever be null?

Comment: If you search on debugging for your environment you can get a stack trace and see what is going on when it happens.

Comment: in TEST_F(), You are inserting different values, but in the end they all are one and only one list element, there is only one address, That doesn't look right at all.

Comment: You may find [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) helpful. There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: from the way the code is formatted now, it looks like you need to uncomment (only) the line `temp->next = new_node;` that will preserve forward searching your linked list as well as the backward searching that you currently preserve with the existing `new_node->prev = temp;` the way the code is written when a new node is inserted the old tail node's `next` pointer is not set to point to the newly added node

Comment: @LucasRoberts.  I'd also like to see the declaration for `list` :)

Comment: Oh.  `list->prev`, the element before the head of the list, should always be NULL, shouldn't it?  This line will always seg fault: `ASSERT_EQ(list->prev->data, &i);`.  Even after the fix proposed by Lucas Roberts.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy it could be the `list->prev` too, I guess it depends on if the OP is using a doubly linked list with sentinel nodes or not but usually the next pointer ***points*** to the sentinel so I'd guess this segfaults too.

Comment: @LucasRoberts It's possible....  If Saurav had posted the declaration for `list`, we'd know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to summarize the comments.

There are likely at least 3 issues with the code as written:

1. When the code `void linked_list_add(list_node_t *head, void *item)` is passed arguments, you generally want to be able to handle a `NULL` pointer for `head`. It looks like the while loop immediately goes into searching for the end of the list even if the `head` is null.
2. The newly added node, `new_node` gets the `prev` pointer updated so that the backwards searchs will be and shouldn't segfault. However, the *forward* searching isn't preserved. By this I mean that the last non-`NULL` node in the linked list doesn't have the `next` pointer pointing to the `new_node`.
3. The test `ASSERT_EQ(list->prev->data, &i);` is likely accessing either a random memory location or a `NULL` pointer. Given that the OP didn't post the declaration of the `list` struct it is difficult to say what the default values are/will be. However, unless this list is circular, the value of  `list->prev` is an uninitialized pointer. Depending on your setup (e.g. if there is setup code for the linked list that sets the pointers to null, you could be accessing a `NULL` pointer there too.

I hope this helps the OP solve their coding problem(s).